# How do you make the onStart and onComplete events work for the xp:pager

Tags: xpages, overlay

I use a full page overlay to display a Loading mask for my XPages. This works fine for most xp controls, buttons, combo boxes, checkboxes etc by adding CSJS to call the overlay on the onStart() and onComplete() events of the event handler. However this does not work with the xp:Pager control. The onStart and onComplete events are available for each part of the pager but they do not seem to activate. I have some big repeat controls whereby the pager refresh can take several seconds so having the overlay is essential to let the user know the pager is working.

I have added my code to the onStart and onComplete of the xp:Pager elements but they simply do not run. The loader works for all other xp elements. I have tried partial refresh and Full Update but neither cause the onStart and onComplete events to trigger?

```
<xp:pager partialRefresh="true" id="pager1" for="displayData">
 <xp:pagerControl type="First" id="pagerControl1">
  <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
  refreshMode="partial" refreshId="questionBlock" 
  onStart="makeButtonInactive('','');" onComplete="makeButtonActive('','');">
  </xp:eventHandler>
 </xp:pagerControl>
 <xp:pagerControl type="Previous" id="pagerControl2">
  <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
refreshMode="partial" refreshId="pagerControl1" onStart="makeButtonInactive('','');"
onComplete="makeButtonActive('','');">
  </xp:eventHandler>
 </xp:pagerControl>
 <xp:pagerControl type="Group" id="pagerControl3">
  <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
refreshMode="partial" refreshId="pagerControl1" onStart="makeButtonInactive('','');"
onComplete="makeButtonActive('','');">
  </xp:eventHandler>
 </xp:pagerControl>
 <xp:pagerControl type="Next" id="pagerControl5">
  <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
refreshMode="partial" refreshId="pagerControl1" onStart="makeButtonInactive('','');"
onComplete="makeButtonActive('','');">
  </xp:eventHandler>
 </xp:pagerControl>
 <xp:pagerControl type="Last" id="pagerControl6">
  <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
refreshMode="partial" refreshId="pagerControl1" onStart="makeButtonInactive('','');"
onComplete="makeButtonActive('','');">
 </xp:eventHandler>
 </xp:pagerControl>
</xp:pager>
```

The makeButtonActive() and makeButtonInactive() functions simply CSJS functions to display a page overlay or an individual button overlay. In this care I am trying to do a full page overlay so the only code that will run is

```
onStart(document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";)
```

and

```
onComplete(document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";)
```

the full funtions are

```
function makeButtonActive(btnId, innerId) {
if (btnId=="") {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none"; //Full Page
} else {
    document.getElementById(btnId).disabled=false;      //Button Only
    document.getElementById(innerId).className=tmpclassName;
}
}
```

and

```
function makeButtonInactive(btnId, innerId) {
if (btnId=="") {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block"; //Full Page
} else {    
    document.getElementById(btnId).disabled=true; //Button Only
    tmpclassName=document.getElementById(innerId).className;
    document.getElementById(innerId).className="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh gly-sm gly-spin";
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most developers I know use Fredrik Norling's Standby Dialog Custom control from OpenNTF. You might be able to work out what's different by cross-referencing, or it might be easier to just use this instead.

If you're using a bootstrap theme, use [this one](https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=standby-dialog-custom-control). If you're using OneUI or non-standard theme, use [this one](https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=standby-dialog-custom-control).

Comment: Thanks Paul, I will give that a go to see if it works, I only want to inform the user that the XPage is working so to wait, so this sounds like a viable solution.